# Como fazer uma "equivalência" de IO em Java e C++?

Tags: java, c++, característica-linguagem

Eu fiz o seguinte código em C++:

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename type> class Foo
{
    public:
    Foo(type FooTest)
    {
        std::cout << "Foo " << FooTest;
    }
};

int main
{
    new Foo<double>(10.0);
}
```

Output: "Foo 10".

Java: (MainClass.java)

```
public class MainClass
{

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            new Foo<Double>(10.0);
        }
}

    class Foo<type>
    {
        public Foo(type FooTest)
        {
            System.out.print("Foo ");
            System.out.print(FooTest);
        }
    }
```

Output: "Foo 10.0".

Este, apenas um caso para demonstrar o que ocorre, o output é diferente nos dois casos para double. Como eu posso igualá-los (Java = 10 e C++ = 10.0) ?

Comment: Não é o foco da pergunta mas acho importante ressaltar que seu código em C++ faz algumas coisas não recomendadas/desnecessárias, como a utilização de `new` neste caso ( causando um vazamento de memória ) e a criação de uma classe para uma função que poderia ser solta.

Comment: @TiagoGomes É claro. Se eu quiser fazer um código **demonstrativo**, não devo me preocupar muito com melhorias; mesmo assim, para fazer um código semelhante em Java, o correto é usar orientação-a-objetos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A formatação padrão no C++ tenta agir de forma "inteligente" e descarta zeros a partir da casa decimal que não interferem no valor, se você colocar `1.1` nos dois, verá que a saída será a mesma.

Para ter uma formatação de precisão fixa você pode usar o manipulador [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) acompanhado do [`std::fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed).

Comment: +1 por usar o std :). Em Java (se houvesse como manipulá-lo), eu faria um cast do objeto para Double. Você conhece uma solução melhor?

Comment: @LucasHenrique Não entendi a pergunta, o que está indo pra saída já é um valor `Double` então pra quê o cast que você diz que faria?

Comment: Por exemplo, (em Java,) fazer uma função que cheque se o número tem casas decimais não nulas. Se retornar falso (não tem), transformar o número em int para mostrá-lo como `10`. `bool has_decimal(double num) { return num%1==0;}`

Comment: @LucasHenrique ah, não faço idéia nem programo Java pra falar a verdade, recomendo uma busca nas opções de formatação nas bibliotecas. Você pode pender pra um dos lados: usar formatação fixa no dois, ou tentar seguir o que o C++ faz no Java, que nem você está perguntando.

Comment: @LucasHenrique A resposta pro Java ter esse comportamento é essa: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14126736/1000282

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar o `printf` :)

## C / C++

```
printf("Foo %.01f", fooTest);
```

## Java

```
System.out.printf("Foo %.01f", fooTest);
```

É claro que esse é um caso específico para `double`, como você está usando um tipo genérico seria interessante declarar uma **interface** comum em ambos os sistemas (ou então declarar *wrappers* que façam a sobrescrita do o `operator<<` no C++ e o método `toString` no Java), de forma que cada tipo saiba como "se imprimir".

Comment: Para o C++ você pode utilizar as funções width e precision. Veja http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/

Comment: Sim, e no Java o [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), mas é bacana usar o mesmo método nos dois :).